# How to connect to XMPP server from Javascript

Tags: javascript, xmpp

I've been looking around for information about XMPP and JavaScr-er, ECMAScript and XMPP. After doing some research,  i found Strophe. It looks intriguing and i was able to get some code to compile (always a starting point for me :) ) but no connection was actually being made.  That's when i realized (thanks to some more research) that a) i couldn't really connect to a different server than the one that issued the page response because it'd be some sort of cross-site scripting or what not, and b) the server (Google Talk) i was trying to connect to didn't have a BOSH whatever. 
So. My question is sort of twofold:
1) Can i connect to a common XMPP server (say, Facebook chat or Google Talk) from a page issued by my server using javascript? (no plugins)
2) If so, how? will Strophe work? (i've heard a lot about WebSockets too, not quite sure what they are or if they'll work.)
 Thanks.

Comment: So what you actually want to do is have your website allow for Google Talk / Facebook Chat facility for the people visiting your site?

Comment: Pretty much, but the whole idea of the site is it isn't a site. It's a web-based chat client...if that makes sense. It'd be like loading Google Talk's Flash Web Client except we want to make it without flash. I can show you a screenshot if that's not clear.

Comment: It's clear what you want to achieve, only problem is that you can't achieve it the way you imagined it. In order to use any of those chats, your user has to be logged on onto one of those websites. After that, Facebook or Google has to allow you to use users' data, which assumes OAuth implementation. After that, you need to have access to the API of the chat implementation. You can't connect directly to their servers, at least to my knowledge. You might be able to emulate something by using iframe and loading the contents of the site and then dynamically changing the layout via JS.

Comment: well, that's not true with Google Talk. The user simply has to authenticate via XMPP. I've sucessfully built a WPF GTalk client - just authenticate the user you would with any XMPP authentication connection.  If Facebook has special restrictions i can understand that... but is there a way to connect to an external XMPP server via JavaScript?

Comment: Would your application use federated servers in order to communicate over XMPP or I got it wrong?

Comment: That's what i'd like to avoid. I want to essentially make an HTML file (including several scripts of course) that anyone could open up on a modern browser and have it connect to an XMPP server. I don't want to make my own XMPP server; i want to conenct to existing ones without having to use my server as an inbetween and without plugins.  People have told me this isn't possible - is that true?

Comment: Well, if it's cross-domain connecting via JS - no, it isn't. That's why you create your own proxy connection in some serverside language that can connect via http to the specified servers and then your JS uses the connection to your own (proxy) server.

Comment: Okay, that's what i wasn't sure on. Thanks! A proxy it is, then. That answers my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For purposes of connecting to various domains over HTTP protocol for data-exchange, JS is limited since POST requests are prohibited due to cross site scripting restrictions (it can be done via IFRAME tho, but for most purposes this isn't viable).

That's why you create a proxy in your preferred server-side language that connects to multiple servers and it acts as a service to which your JS "connects" and uses it to display the data to the browser.

Comment: Do you mean a proxy in HTTP? But this would not be able to achieve real-time communication that XMPP does.